# @RequestMapping on multiple abstract classes

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have 2 abstract classes:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public abstract class AbstractBaseController

@RequestMapping("/agent")
public abstract class AbstractBaseAgentController extends AbstractBaseController
```

then I have a class that extends AbstractBaseAgentController:

```
public class AgentController extends AbstractBaseAgentController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/users")
  public ResponseEntity<RestResponse> listUsers() {...}
}
```

With the class above, I was hoping to reach `"/api/v1/agent/users"` endpoint. However I keep getting 404 Not Found.

Am I doing anything wrong. If so what is the correct way?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `@RequestMapping` on subclass *replaces* `@RequestMapping` on super class. Change subclass to `@RequestMapping("/api/v1/agent")`.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you ! :-)